# How to change dag_default_view in Airflow webserver?

Tags: python, airflow

Airflow v1.8 introduced a change in the UI where clicking a DAG takes you to the "Tree" view, instead of the previously defaulted "Graph" view. According to the documentation, adding/changing this line in the config should alter this behavior, but I haven't had any success:

```
# Default DAG view.  Valid values are:
# tree, graph, duration, gantt, landing_times
dag_default_view = graph
```

https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L220-L222

Am I misreading the instructions? Has anyone been able to successfully get this default behavior to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This change is not actually in the latest stable version (1.8.2). It will be in the next version (1.9.0), as specified in the fix version of [AIRFLOW-903](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-903). The [first release candidate for 1.9.0](https://www.mail-archive.com/dev@airflow.incubator.apache.org/msg03917.html) was cut yesterday, so hopefully that means the change you want will be on the stable version soon.